# Validate that a JsonSchema contains a valid schema in Json.NET

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net, jsonschema

I'm trying to detect if a JsonSchema contains a valid schema.  As far as I can tell, Json.NET doesn't have a way of validating a JSON schema.

It seems that you can create a JsonSchema with a completely invalid schema and it won't complain, like so:

```
var invalidSchema = JsonSchema.Parse(@"{ ""title"": { ""Invalid"": ""Invalid"" } }");
```

You can then go on to validate JObjects against the invalid schema and you will get true back.  For the record, the above "schema" is not valid according to the published [draft-03](http://json-schema.org/draft-03/schema) self-describing schema (I checked with [JSON Schema Lint](http://jsonschemalint.com/)).

I tried to parse the [draft-03](http://json-schema.org/draft-03/schema) to validate other schemas against it, but I didn't get very far with that.  I get an exception when I try to parse it:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=Exception JSON schema type string token, got StartObject. Path 'properties.type.items.type[1]', line 11, position 6.
  Source=Newtonsoft.Json
  LineNumber=11
  LinePosition=6
  Path=properties.type.items.type[1]
  StackTrace:
       at Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.JsonSchemaBuilder.ProcessType()
       at Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.JsonSchemaBuilder.ProcessSchemaProperty(String propertyName)
       at Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.JsonSchemaBuilder.BuildSchema()
       at Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.JsonSchemaBuilder.ProcessItems()
       at Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.JsonSchemaBuilder.ProcessSchemaProperty(String propertyName)
       at Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.JsonSchemaBuilder.BuildSchema()
       at Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.JsonSchemaBuilder.ProcessProperties()
       at Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.JsonSchemaBuilder.ProcessSchemaProperty(String propertyName)
       at Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.JsonSchemaBuilder.BuildSchema()
       at Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.JsonSchemaBuilder.Parse(JsonReader reader)
       at Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.JsonSchema.Read(JsonReader reader, JsonSchemaResolver resolver)
       at Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.JsonSchema.Parse(String json, JsonSchemaResolver resolver)
       at Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.JsonSchema.Parse(String json)
  InnerException:
```